# .htaccess RewriteRule change domain .com to .jp

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect requests on `abc.com` to `abc.jp` by adding this line to .htaccess file

`RewriteRule ^(.*)abc\.com(.*)$ $1abc.jp$2`

But it didn't work. So confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `RewriteCond` to match the domain, then redirect using `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://abc.jp$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```